# Self-adoint positive operator $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $a$, $b$ be positive numbers. $A$ is a positive self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space, such that $aI \leqslant A \leqslant bI$. How to prove $b^{-1}I \leqslant A^{-1} \leqslant a^{-1}I$?

Comment: It's not true. For example $A=2I$, $a=b=2$.

Comment: It doesn't seems true: take $A=\lambda I$ then $A$ is self adjoint and:
$$\lambda I \leq A \leq \lambda I $$
but:
$$\lambda^{-1} I \leq A \leq \lambda^{-1} I $$
is false if $\lambda \neq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  If $aI\leq A\leq bI$, then $\sigma(A)\subset [a,b]$.  What does this say about $\sigma(A^{-1})$?

Comment: I propose that $\sigma(A^{-1}) \subset{[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]}$, but I can't prove that.

Comment: Use the spectral mapping theorem.